# Accuracy tending towards a number and staying there in MLP (Python Tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, mlp

I've got a pandas dataframe with the following structure:

```
    temp    dewp    humid   wind_dir    wind_speed  precip  visib   delayed
0   39.02   28.04   64.43   260.0       12.65858    0.0     10.0    True
1   39.92   24.98   54.81   250.0       14.96014    0.0     10.0    False
2   39.02   26.96   61.63   260.0       14.96014    0.0     10.0    True
3   39.02   26.96   61.63   260.0       14.96014    0.0     10.0    False
4   39.92   24.98   54.81   260.0       16.11092    0.0     10.0    False
..................................
```

I'm trying to build a MLP (with tensorflow) to predict whether a flight will be delayed or not. I do the following to get the dataframe as an input to my MLP

```
target= flight_info['delayed']

flight_info.pop('delayed')
tf.convert_to_tensor(flight_info)
```

I then do the following:

```
normalizer = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(axis=-1)
normalizer.adapt(flight_info)

def get_basic_model():
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    normalizer,
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    #tf.keras.layers.Dense(15, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
  ])

  model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
                metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model

model = get_basic_model()
model.fit(flight_info, target, epochs=60, batch_size=1000)
```

The accuracy goes up by 0.1 and then stays at that point with loss: 0.1605  and accuracy: 0.7906 even after changing the batch size and epochs numerous times.

What am I doing wrong here, could anyone help me out?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you think is a problem? Getting an accuracy of 0.7906 seems a good starting point.

Comment: it rounds off to a number too quickly from my experiene

Comment: When a model converges quickly to a number, it is usually an indication of a small dataset. Or a big model relative to the data size. If you already have a big dataset (tens of thousands samples and more), probably you will get better results if you start tweaking other parameters of your model along with batch size and epochs such as learning rate, nodes per layers etc.

Comment: This is not an actual problem.